# Is there any anime series of Dragon Ball after Dragon Ball GT?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

I am a great fan of Dragon Ball, and I have watched almost every series and movies of Dragon Ball. However, I'm not sure if there is any other series after Dragon Ball GT.

Comment: There are a ton of [Dragon ball  films](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Ball#Films) that you could watch, but no new series has been made since '97. I think you have to wait until DBZ Kai ends. They can't revamp DBGT to be "closer to the manga", since there is no DBGT manga, so it might be that a new series arises, but only time will tell. I haven't heard of any news related to this, so you shouldn't get your hopes up :(

Comment: Yes! Dragon Ball Super is coming soon and it's believed that it will contain 100+ Episodes.

Comment: Will it be broadcasted on cartoon network? @Ketan

Comment: [This question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/21373/6166) will answer yours ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no anime series of Dragon Ball after Dragon Ball GT.
Dragon Ball Kai has no independent story but is basically the story of Dragon Ball Z itself.

Instead of an anime series, the movie Dragon Ball Z: Battle of Gods was released which is in official continuity with Dragon Ball Z and therefore, before the events of Dragon Ball GT.

This year (2015) the sequel to Battle of Gods - Dragon Ball Z: Resurrection 'F' will be released.

**Update**

A new anime series Dragon Ball Super is going to be aired from July 2015 onwards. It's story will pick up after the events of Resurrection 'F'.

Since the story of Dragon Ball Z has taken a significant turn by introducing the Super Saiyan God ability and other plot events, the fate of Dragon Ball GT is left hanging in the balance. At this minute, there is no official word about whether it will still exist in the continuity of the Dragon Ball Universe or not.

Comment: I think you are right. Your explanations seems legit. :)

Comment: Happy to help a fellow Dragon Ball fan!
:)

Comment: Maybe this answer should be updated by including the planned [Dragon ball Super anime series](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/21373/6166)

Comment: @PeterRaeves updated the answer!

Answer (score 4):

After Dragon Ball GT came [**Dragon Ball Z Kai**](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Z_Kai).

Dragon Ball Z Kai is a high-definition remastered and recut of Dragon Ball Z, done for its 20th Anniversary. The series' plot focuses more on the manga style. The total episode count for the series is 167, comprising of :

1. Saiyan Saga (26 Episodes)
2. Frieza Saga (26 Episodes)
3. Androids Saga (25 Episodes)
4. Cell Saga (21 Episodes)
5. Majin Buu Saga (35 Episodes)
6. Evil Buu Saga

For more details on the episode list, click [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dragon_Ball_Z_Kai_episodes).

Related : [Will I miss anything by watching Dragon Ball Z Kai instead of the other series?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/will-i-miss-anything-by-watching-dragon-ball-z-kai-instead-of-the-other-series?rq=1)

---

**EDIT:**

A new *Dragon Ball* series has been announced, titled: [**Dragon Ball Super**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Super)

From [Dragon Ball Wikia](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Super):

> The plot framework and character designs were created by original author Akira Toriyama. The series will be developed by Toei, in a similar process to the Dragon Ball, Dragon Ball Z, and Dragon Ball GT animes. The beginning of the series plot takes place after the Majin Buu Saga, potentially putting it in either the 10 year gap towards the 28th World Martial Arts Tournament, or afterwards.

> Dragon Ball Super is set to begin airing in Japan on Fuji TV, July 5th, 2015.
>
> <sup><sup>source: http://www.dragonballinsider.com/2015/05/03/dragon-ball-super-start-date-of-july-5-2015/</sup></sup>

Comment: I have seen Dragonballz Kai , it focuses on the story of Kai's supreme Kai, etc . Dragonball Gt consist of new transformation known as super saiyan 4. So Dragonball GT was the latest anime series of Dragonball according to me @Ero

Comment: What do you want to prove? **Goku** is the main character of the story , it's obvious that he will be given the major importance. No doubt the dbz Kai focuses on world of Kai's. Kai's have important role till the end of the dbz .

Comment: Yeah..! I forgot to mention the importance of **Goku** but you take that seriously.

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of sarcastic in this situation?

Comment: Maybe this answer should be updated by including the planned [Dragon ball Super anime series](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/21373/6166)

Answer (score 4):

Following the storyline, after [Dragon Ball GT](http://myanimelist.net/anime/225/Dragon_Ball_GT), there was [Dragon Ball GT: A Hero's Legacy](http://myanimelist.net/anime/987/Dragon_Ball_GT:_Goku_Gaiden!_Yuuki_no_Akashi_wa_Suushinchuu).

The story ends with the TV special mentioned above.

Meanwhile, the same series were remastered/revised ([Dragon Ball Kai](http://myanimelist.net/anime/6033/Dragon_Ball_Kai), [Dragon Ball Kai (2014)](http://myanimelist.net/anime/22777/Dragon_Ball_Kai_%282014%29)), also two new movies [Dragon Ball Z: Battle of Gods](http://myanimelist.net/anime/14837/Dragon_Ball_Z_Movie_14:_Kami_to_Kami) and [Dragon Ball Z: Resurrection ‘F’](http://myanimelist.net/anime/25389/Dragon_Ball_Z_Movie_15:_Fukkatsu_no_F) (this movies takes place on Frieza Saga).