# Dragon Ball Super release date

Tags: dragon-ball-super

I'm sure you've heard the news about the new *Dragon Ball* series *Dragon Ball Super*, made by Akira Toriyama.

I've read about it and the release date is in June or July (can't remember).
We're talking about manga, right or brand new episodes?

If it's just the manga, is it already known when we can expect brand new *Dragon Ball* episodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Dragonball Super*** will be animated rather than a manga version and released on J*uly 5th, 2015* in Japan

Source: http://attackofthefanboy.com/news/rumor-dragon-ball-super-go-long-100-episodes/

Answer (score 3):

Toei Animation have announced that they will indeed make a manga for the upcoming Dragon Ball anime series, "Dragon Ball Super", with the Dragon Ball creator, and author Akira Toriyama and the Dragon Ball: Heroes Victory Mission author, Toyotoro. Now we see if they can deliver for us that we really want to see, that Dragon Ball GT did not deliver to the Dragon Ball fans. We may see the other 12 gods that Beerus mentioned in the Dragon Ball Z: Battle of Gods film, Uub, Gohan's coming back to training, a first ever Female Super Saiyan, new villains, and a lot more that we wanted to experience it, and fun epic adventures too. Just like the original Dragon Ball, and Dragon Ball Z.