# What is the difference between Dragonball Z and Dragonball Z Kai?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

When I first heard about Kai thought it was a Remake similar to the recent Sailor Moon Remake (not Crystal the original series where Haruka and Michiru were made to be cousins to censor their relationship). however i have seen posts that seem to indicate that the first few Sagas have been covered in less episodes in Kai.

So i am wondering what is the difference between the original Dragonball Z and Dragonball Z Kai? eg. What has been added/removed in comparison, do people bleed when their limbs get cut/ripped off (when i first saw DBZ there was never any blood)

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: [Will I miss anything by watching Dragon Ball Z Kai instead of the other series?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3010/274)

Comment: The main difference is that there are no fillers and generally improved animation.

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply: DragonBall Z Kai is a remake which stays true to the original DragonBall Z Manga. A quick list of the main differences:

- No Fillers.
- Different theme songs.
- Some Different Voice Actors (in e.g: Frieza, Gohan, Android 18).
- Less Blood.

**Note:** *Don't watch the censored version, you'll hate it.*

Comment: Adding to Serge R. Kamel, people say the quality is better (not terrible 480p) and been revamped to 720p+ That's false, It is still low quality (compared to the "newer" animes), however the intro's are HD and look good. BTW - DB Super is in 1080p :3