# Is there a difference between Dragon Ball Z, Dragon Ball Kai and Dragon Ball Z Kai?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball

After doing a little research, I saw that Dragon Ball Z Kai and Dragon Ball Kai are the same and that they are just remakes of Dragon Ball Z. Is this correct?

I know that Dragon Ball Z has around 300 episodes and that Dragon Ball Z Kai and Dragon Ball Kai stop after the stage with cell around 100 episodes. So which one is better for watching with an English dub?

Comment: I don't think we could answer a subjective question about which one is better in English dub. That part of your post is a separate question, and on its own it wouldn't be on topic here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will I miss anything by watching Dragon Ball Z Kai instead of the other series?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/will-i-miss-anything-by-watching-dragon-ball-z-kai-instead-of-the-other-series)

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to say which is better because it is a matter of personal opinion. The idea of Dragon Ball Z Kai is to take the best parts of Dragon Ball Z (there was A LOT of filler) and put them together in a better art style (the art "quality" was not as good in the 80's; Kai was made in the 2000's).

The idea was that Dragon Ball Z continually got ahead of its source material, the manga, because it had to make a 20 minute episode every week going along with only 15 pages of manga a week; they would compensate for this by adding in filler episodes to allow the manga to catch back up. So, when they finished Dragon Ball GT, they decided to go ahead and remaster Dragon Ball Z. This time they had all of the source material, and animation technology was better, allowing for a "higher quality" animation. This allowed them to cut out all the filler and just have content that pertains to the story, all in great animation and music.

The reason I put higher quality in quotes is that quality is subjective. I personally like the old style better because I think that the characters are more expressive and the animation has more character; however, the new animation looks really slick and the music is awesome in Kai. It is worth trying out both and seeing for yourself which you prefer, and you can always skip the filler in Dragon Ball Z.

Answer (score 2):

Since there can't​ be one particular answer to this question and others can only give you their opinions, I will say Dragon Ball Z original is much better than Kai and I liked the old voices more than the new ones in the dub version.

The other thing is Dragon Ball Z Kai does not have any fillers. I have watched both, and I even thought that losing all the fillers would be a great thing, but I mostly found it frustrating. Some of Gohan's more awesome rage moments were shortened and worse yet the battles just were not as exciting.

Answer (score 2):

Dragon Ball Z Kai is Dragon Ball Z without the fillers.

Answer (score 0):

Dragon ball Z is the second adaptation of the dragon ball manga, dragon ball kai is a remake of it with less filler, new animated scenes, new script, reworked voice acting, new music

if you are willing to watch dragon ball with filler, aged animation, old voice acting and music, then Z is the way to go

if not, then kai is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Dragon Ball Z Kai and Dragon Ball Kai are the same rework of the original DBZ. It is called Dragon Ball Kai in Japan just as Dragon Ball Z is called Dragon Ball in Japan. If you want to know the storyline and the main sagas of DBZ then watch Kai, if you want to see all the fillers then you should watch the original DBZ.