# From which series should I start watching Dragon Ball?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball

I know that *Dragon Ball* is a very long saga.

- Which series should I start with?
- Is there any of the new ones the reboot of the old ones?
- If I start with *Dragon Ball Super*, will it be continuing the others, or is it a reboot of the first one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. If you want to start with the beginning, start with ***Dragon Ball***. If you want to start with the most popular segment (probably the most entertaining segment, but this is a matter of opinion), start with ***Dragon Ball Z***. Many people haven't seen *Dragon Ball* and yet they understand most of what follows it without watching *Dragon Ball*.
2. I don't know if ***Dragon Ball Z Kai*** counts exactly as a "reboot", but it is a modified version of ***Dragon Ball Z***, in HD, with new color, new lines, new backgrounds, re-recorded voices and sound effects, new openings and endings, new background music, deleted scenes and episodes, etc.
3. ***Dragon Ball Super*** is a continuation of ***Dragon Ball Z*** and ***Dragon Ball***.

Comment: so watching Dragon Ball Z Kai instead of the original Dragon Ball Z is a viable option?

Comment: @TheFlow0360 https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/will-i-miss-anything-by-watching-dragon-ball-z-kai-instead-of-the-other-series/3015#3015

Answer (score 2):

*Dragon Ball Super* is the latest iteration of *Dragon Ball* (as of current writing). I recommend starting with *Dragon Ball*, followed by *Dragon Ball Z* and then watch *Dragon Ball Super* if you wish to watch all the episodes in order and in succession.

There is also *Dragon Ball GT* which isn't canon with the original series. You could perhaps consider it as something which happens in an alternate timeline and watch it after *Dragon Ball Z*. Please note that *Dragon Ball Super* is the actual continuation of *Dragon Ball Z*.